# How to put exposed filter in a separate block in a view in drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7

With drupal 6 I could easily choose to have the exposed filters in a separate block which I could then put on the sidebar. I can't figure out how to do that in drupal 7. Anyone know?
Thanks,
Diana

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a page view
2. Adjust the settings

   > [image: screenshot]
3. Make sure you expand the advanced tab

Comment: Hi Jeff, I only saw that option in the drupal 6 .  I dont see that in drupal 7 with views 3.0

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your view?

Comment: you're right ! I suddenly saw it and I couldnt see it before . sorry and thank you.

Comment: There should be a checkmark below the number of votes on my answer.  Go here if you can't find it: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

For D7 blocks, setting 'Use AJAX' to Yes worked for me.

Also, with two blocks on the same page filtering the same fields (but different data/views), it seems applying a filter from one block affects both blocks. Not sure how to work around that yet.

Clarification: In Advanced -> Other, set 'Use AJAX' to Yes

Comment: Please clarify your answer

Answer (score -1):

For D7 use module - Views Block Exposed Filter Blocks
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_filter_block

After enable this module you will see new settings in Exposed Form fieldset
see screenshot - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFtg.png)

This solution also works with panels.